# Color Themes in VSC: "background color of selected word"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, background-color, color-scheme

I'm working on a color theme for VS Code.
I try to edit the background color which is used when you click on a word (not search - just click.)

I can't find the correct setting which is responsible for the color of this scope.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why I didn't find it... it's simply:

```
"editor.selectionBackground": "#ff8800",
"editor.selectionForeground": "#ff0000"
```